# How to carry out the total count on the sum of each group (X,Y) individually and remove any groups that has zeros on python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
    df = df.groupby(['X', 'Y'])['STATUS'].sum()
```

The output:

```
X  Y 
1  41    0
   42    0
   43    0
   44    0
   45    0
Name: STATUS, dtype: int64
```

The next step is to count the groupby X and Y. Now there will be some X and Y groups that will have a Status sum of 2 or more which is correct so far e.g.

```
X  Y 
2  41    0
   42    1
   43    2
   44    0
   45    1
```

See in X,Y = 2,43 has a sum of 2 but I want the output to be duplicate copies based on the sum of 2 or greater and also get rid of any group that has zero. This is for mapping on the software I have at the moment.

```
 X  Y 
 2  42    1
    43    1
    43    1
    45    1
```

You saw 2,43 came up twice but it is counted as 1 individually and there are no zeros as we removed that. So can you please advise me how to do it?

Let me know if you need me to elaborate it more and appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum_vals=df.groupby(['X','Y'])['STATUS'].sum().reset_index()
sum_vals=sum_vals[sum_vals['STATUS']>0]
sum_vals=sum_vals.loc[sum_vals.index.repeat(sum_vals.STATUS)]
sum_vals['STATUS']=1
```

Comment: it works out brilliantly! Thanks for your help, you just saved me countless hours of work.